# Compare string null or empty in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

In my table of MySQL Db I have the field `Check`.

The value memorized on the field `Check` it could be : `null` or `-1`.

When the value memorized on the field `Check` is `null` or `-1` I need in return the `xxx` value. and I have tried :

```
string Check = sdr["Check"] == DBNull.Value || sdr["Check"] == "-1,00" ? "xxx" : sdr["Check"].ToString();
```

Without success because the output is always `-1,00`.

How to do resolve this?

Please help me, thank you so much in advance.

Comment: "The output is -1,00". Do you mean that `sdr["Check"].ToString()` is always -1,00?

Comment: Yes the value of `sdr["Check"].ToString()` is always -1,00

Comment: what happen if you do not check for `.Value` but using `sdr["Check"] == DBNull` or `sdr["Check"] is DBNull` instead?

Comment: Use parenthesis and cover the entire ternary conditional. The way it's written, the meaning is "`sdr["Check"] == DBNull.Value || ( sdr["Check"] == "-1,00" ? "xxx" : sdr["Check"])` "

Comment: Said that, I believe you should have 
`(sdr["Check"] == DBNull.Value || sdr["Check"] == "-1,00") ? "xxx" : sdr["Check"].ToString()` instead

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are comparing the wrong objects.  The values returned from `System.Data` result sets are wrappers around the actual value.  What you want are the typed versions.  Basically, the check should look like this:

```
int checkIndex = sdr.GetOrdinal("Check");
string Check = sdr.IsDBNull(checkIndex) || (sdr.GetString(checkIndex) == "-1,00") ? "xxx" : sdr.GetString(checkIndex);
```

If you "Check" is actually a number, you may want to use the `IntValue("Check")` call, just to deal with globalization issues if your app is ever deployed where they use a "." instead of a "," for your decimal point.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx for the full API.

---

If your MySQL database is not set to use the same locale formatting as your C# application, your assumptions about number formats could be incorrect.  To make a more robust version of your check, I would recommend something like this:

```
 int checkIndex = sdr.GetOrdinal("Check");
 string Check = "xxx";
 double checkValue = sdr.IsDBNull(checkIndex) ? -1 : Convert.ToDouble(sdr[checkIndex]);

 if (checkValue != -1)
 {
     Check = checkValue.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried your suggestion but the output no change. I have always -1,00

Comment: CS1061: 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'IsDbNull' and no extension method 'IsDbNull' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Question: have you looked at the return value of `sdr.GetString("Check")`?  If it's actually a number field, then MySQL could be formatting it as "-1.00" or simply "-1".  I'll post an addendum to handle that.

Comment: In MySQL is -1 in debug is -1.00

Comment: `IsDbNull` does not take a `string` it takes an `int` that is the ordinal position of the column.  You can get that with `sdr.GetOrdinal("Check")`

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq, I've adjusted my answer to deal with the culture specific number formatting.

Comment: Thank you, but with your last code I have the same error `Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'IsDbNull' and no extension method 'IsDbNull' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx  Looks like I got my capitalization wrong.

Comment: The syntas is `IsDBNull` now the error is `Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`

Comment: What is the SQL data type of that column?

Comment: If you use `Convert.ToDouble()` it will convert just about any SQL Data Type, string, etc. to a double if there is any conversion path possible.  I've had some funny restrictions based on SQL field types not converting cleanly to something you would otherwise expect to be equivalent.

Comment: SQL data type is decimal 10,2

Comment: That explains it.  The Decimal SQL data type is pretty special.  The `Convert.ToDouble()` call _should_ solve your problem though.

Answer (score 0):

If the data type is **decimal 10,2** you need `Convert.ToDecimal` the value :

```
 string Check = (sdr["Check"] == DBNull.Value || Convert.ToDecimal(sdr["Check"]) == -1) ? "xxx" : sdr["Check"].ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can compare a string empty or null by below code

```
string str = Your string
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
{
    if yes, it comes here
}
else
{
    if not, it comes here
}
```

The `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` is a `bool` type.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't answer the problem.

Comment: correct if i am wrong, you are checking the string is null or empty

Comment: In a SQL DB Data Reader.

Comment: The OP is actually working with an `object` that might be a `string`, a `DBNull`, or something else.

Comment: SQL DB Data Readers don't return strings.  It's an object, which could be DBNull (which itself is an object), or some other database specific representation.  String.IsNullOrEmpty() only compares strings or the C# `null`.  Neither of which you've described how to get.